# Receive an update when you Receive an Email

Tags: node.js, email, sdk, smtp, webhooks

I am using Gmail with Amazon SES to send Emails using SMTP. I want a request on a WebHook I created (in java) when I receive a new message on the Email. Like when I sent a Mail to test123@gmail.com using SMTP integration I have and test123@gmail.com writes a reply to my Email, how can I immediately get to know about that?

If I'm supposed to use a SDK to integrate the same, which SDK can help me do so.

I'm not sure whether I have to integrate with Gmail or with SES to do this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) in Gmail API.
There are a lot of services that offer this feature like Zapier, but it costs money. This is your best bet if you want to implement your a solution for your requirement without spending tons of money.

Comment: I got your answer but what if I am using some other Mail Platform as well, like Zoho Mail, Outlook, Yahoo and many more. Is there a standard was to do that? Maybe using some library in Java or Python.

Comment: Pretty sure there is no free package or library available which works for all email providers. If you are looking at paid services, there are platforms like Zapier which offer exactly as per your needs and a lot of other functionalities.